# [Nuxt.js/Typescript]how to get data from vuex?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm a Typescript newbie. I set Objective Data to Vuex store, but I can't get it.

This is the Objective data of Users(in other words, `account`).

```
# models/User.ts

export interface IUser {
  email: string | null
  name: string | null
}

export class UserClass implements IUser {
  email: string | null
  name: string | null

  constructor(email: string | null, name: string | null) {
    this.email = email
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

```
# store/accounts.ts

import { UserClass } from '~/models/User'

@Module({ stateFactory: true, namespaced: true, name: 'account'})
export default class Account extends VuexModule {
  user: UserClass | null = null

  get currentUser() {
    return this.user
  }

  @Mutation
  storeUser(user: UserClass | null){
    this.user = user
  }

  @Action({})
  setUser(user: UserClass | null){
    this.storeUser(user)
  }
}
```

```
# utils/store-accessor.ts

import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import Account from '~/store/account'

let accountStore: Account

function initializeStore(store: Store<any>): void {
  accountStore = getModule(Account, store))
}
export { initializeStore, accountStore }
```

```
# components/Sample.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <p>NAME: {{currentUser.email}}</p>    // ★error !
  </div>
</template>
export default class SampleCmp extends Vue {
  @Prop() currentUser: UserClass | null = accountStore.currentUser
}
```

I want to get email like above `currentUser．email`, but got error `Cannot read property 'email' of null`.
If it set just `currentUser`, the stored data like `{email: hogehoge@test.com, name: dummy}` is output to page as it is.

what should I do ? please help !

regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `vuex-class` library, which is already installed with `nuxt-property-decorator`.

When declaring your component, import also the namespace from nuxt-property-decorator:

```
import { Vue, Component, namespace } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
const user = namespace('user')
```

Then you can access your `user` store properties like this using `vuex-class` decorators:

```
@user.Getter
public currentUser!: string


@user.Mutation
public storeUser!: (data: UserClass | null) => void

@user.Action
public setUser(user: UserClass | null) => void
```

You can find more on this topic in the vuex section of [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-set-up-and-code-nuxt-js-apps-fully-in-typescript/) article.

Alternatively, the official nuxt typescript [documentation](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/store.html#nuxt-typed-vuex) suggests to try the `nuxt-typed-vuex` package.

Comment: Thanks for your advise ! I'll try it.